# Entity Framework : Insert causes violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint using Azure SQL, not local

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure

I'm in the process of migrating a local SQL Server 2014 database for use in Azure. I have an Asp.net MVC app running in IIS 8, connected to an Azure SQL Server database using Entity Framework in the usual way.

1. I have a `dbContext`
2. `Using(... dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())`
3. other entities added and `SaveChanges()` runs successfully
4. For one entity in particular, I do `db.entity.add(newEntity)`, then `SaveChanges()` and I get:

   > Exception: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_entity'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.entity'. The duplicate key value is (2).

The primary key is an auto increment number and I'm the only user running this. There are 156 records in this table already.

What's bizarre is that this works fine when I run this on my local machine using a local SQL Server instance, but when run from IIS and Azure db, this exception occurs.

The entity has no other relations/constraints at all.

I do feel there may be a clue in that if I keep trying to save this record (ISS and Azure), the failed duplicate key value increments by 1 each time.

Comment: `There are 156 records in this table already` - SELECT * FROM thistable please?

Comment: If you can delete all records from that table and then try to `add()`. That will prove if error was not because of existing data.

Comment: Minimally share the table DDL and relevant part of the EF model, and the EF log (db.Database.Log = m => MyLogger(m)) of the database traffic causing the error.  Preferably boil the problem down to a complete, self-contained repro.  While you're doing that you'll probably discover the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That´s very strange, maybe the index of identity coll in Azure Bd is set to 1.
You can force your identity coll to a index greater than your last Id in table:

In sql server you can check next Id:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('tablename') AS Current_Identity;
```

You can force it to other number:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('tablename', RESEED, 157);
```

Comment: After tested DBCC command on my Azure SQL database, I found that I need to remove the Identitycoll to make the command worked fine.  DBCC CHECKIDENT ('tablename', RESEED, 157);

Comment: Thanks Rui. For a table of 156, `IDENT_CURRENT` returned 6!

Comment: That is the problem, you have to fix the index, as the Amor - MSFT comments the correct command is  DBCC CHECKIDENT ('tablename', RESEED, 157);

Comment: I ran `DBCC CHECKIDENT` but now I get **The duplicate key value is (158).**

Comment: You have to check what is your Higher key in the table, and set RESEED to after that. for example if your higher key is 1000, you set to 1001.